# rest design for object related

Tags: spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

A lodger can have many reference and a reference is only associated to one lodger

I created a method to search reference related to a lodgerId

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers/{lodgerId}/references", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Reference getReferenceByUserId(@PathVariable("lodgerId") long lodgerId) {
    return referenceService.getReferenceByLodgerId(lodgerId);
}
```

In term of design, it's it better to put it in the rest controller related to lodger or reference

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any orm,JPA,etc then getting the references for a particular lodger becomes a very natural choice to be put into the controller related to lodger and operation related a particular reference in reference controller.
Even if you are not using any any of the mention framework the above set up seems very obvious.